# Wikimedia API - extraction data

Tags: javascript, xml, api, wikipedia

How to extract the content of a Wikipedia article in the form of xml / html / json or even?

This method extracts the data in the format BBCode:
http://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Wikipedia:Skarbnica%20Wikipedii/Wynalazki%20wieku%20XIX&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&callback=?

I can not use this data using Javascript because I do not like to refer to them.
How to parse it?
Maybe there is a special library to help use the data?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following code in the Chrome console (press F12) and click on the console log output to inspect the returned object.

```
(function(){
 var callbackName="cb";
 window[callbackName]=function(data){
   s.parentElement.removeChild(s);
   console.log(data);
   if(!data.query || !data.query.pages){
     //unexpected object, return
     return;
   }
   for(page in data.query.pages){
     console.log(data.query.pages[page]);
   }

 };
 var s = document.createElement("script");
 s.src="http://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?"+
  "format=json&action=query&titles=Wikipedia:"+
  "Skarbnica%20Wikipedii/Wynalazki%20wieku%20"+
  "XIX&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&callback="+
  escape(callbackName);
 document.body.appendChild(s);
}());
```

If you want wikipedia to return other data then check out their api: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Answer (score 0):

The returned data is not in [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), it's [wikicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_markup) (markup language specific to MediaWiki).

If you want to get the results parsed into HTML, add `&rvparse` to your query. For example: http://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=Wikipedia:Skarbnica%20Wikipedii/Wynalazki%20wieku%20XIX&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvparse

Comment: That's someone helping me but the output is still not valid HTML it looks something like `this:title=\"Portal:Technology\">Technology</a>\n` is there a way to get "real" HTML without `\n` and all those escaped `"`

Comment: @hashier That's exactly how HTML inside JSON *should* look like. If you use a proper JSON parser, it will give you the HTML you're expecting.

Comment: Okay, I didn't even try this since it looked "broken" in the console. Thanks. I wished I could up vote you more than from -1 to 0 ):